# How do I get the binding target in a guice provider?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is there a way to get the class into which something is being injected in a provider (or some other way)? This is for logging -- When my `SqlDatabase` does something, I want it to show up in the logs with the name of the class in which it's being used. The best I can think of is to get the stack trace and go backwards through that to find out where it's used, but I would really rather do it at injection time.

A different way to put the question is: I need to find the injection site -- the exact class where the `@Inject` annotation was found -- to create the instance of the injected class.

Comment: If you are targeting Java 9, you can use the new stack walking API: https://www.javaworld.com/article/3188289/core-java/java-9s-other-new-enhancements-part-5-stack-walking-api.html

Comment: @TomG - I found out a more guice-specific way to do it, but that API is really cool. Took long enough for them to add it :-) .

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a... thing... that seems to work:

```
import com.google.inject.Binder;
import com.google.inject.Binding;
import com.google.inject.Key;
import com.google.inject.matcher.AbstractMatcher;
import com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher;
import com.google.inject.spi.DependencyAndSource;
import com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import com.google.inject.spi.ProvisionListener;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.Provider;

/**
 * This is a dirty, dirty hack to allow some types to know what they're being injected into. There are other
 * (possibly cleaner) ways to do this, but this has the nice advantage of the injected class not needing
 * to know anything about this.
 */
public class ContextAwareInjection
{
    public static <T> void bindContextAwareProvider(Binder binder, Class<T> type, Function<InjectionPoint, T> provider)
    {
        bindContextAwareProvider(binder, Key.get(type), provider);
    }

    public static <T> void bindContextAwareProvider(Binder binder, Key<T> key, Function<InjectionPoint, T> provider)
    {
        Matcher<Binding<?>> matcher = new AbstractMatcher<Binding<?>>() {
            @Override public boolean matches(Binding<?> binding) { return binding.getKey().equals(key); } };
        ContextAwareImpl<T> impl = new ContextAwareImpl<>(provider, key);
        binder.bind(key).toProvider(impl);
        binder.bindListener(matcher, impl);
    }

    private static class ContextAwareImpl<T> implements ProvisionListener, Provider<T>
    {
        private final Key<T> key;
        private final Function<InjectionPoint, T> provider;
        private final ThreadLocal<T> current = new ThreadLocal<>();

        private ContextAwareImpl(Function<InjectionPoint, T> provider, Key<T> key)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public <T2> void onProvision(ProvisionInvocation<T2> pi)
        {
            if(!pi.getBinding().getKey().equals(key))
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected key -- got " + pi.getBinding().getKey() + ", expected " + key);
            try
            {
                List<DependencyAndSource> chain = pi.getDependencyChain();
                if(chain.isEmpty())
                    throw new RuntimeException("This should never be empty");
                DependencyAndSource das = chain.get(chain.size() - 1);
                InjectionPoint ip = das == null || das.getDependency() == null ? null : das.getDependency().getInjectionPoint();
                T value = provider.apply(ip);
                if(value == null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("Context aware providers should never return null");
                current.set(value);
                pi.provision();
            }
            finally
            {
                current.remove();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public T get()
        {
            T value = current.get();
            if(value == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("There is no current value -- this should never happen");
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

This may have some slight runtime performance implications, but for tests it works fine. More importantly, it requires *no changes at all* to the target classes. You can keep using `@Inject` as you always were.

Comment: 6 years later, it is still an issue and was refused to be solved by Guice folks in official API: https://github.com/google/guice/pull/1721. The dependency information is stripped from guice as well, so above solution works up to certain version of Guice.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two alternatives:

1. Use `@Provides` methods when declaring your bindings
2. Use [Guice AOP](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) so you can log actual method execution

Here's a toy example of both approaches:

```
package stackoverflowscrapbook;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import com.google.inject.matcher.Matchers;

public class TestLogInjectedClassName {

    interface SqlDatabase {
        void doSomething();
    }

    static class SqlDatabaseImpl implements SqlDatabase {

        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("foo");
        }

    }

    static class AlternativeImpl implements SqlDatabase {

        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("bar");
        }

    }

    class Module extends AbstractModule {

        @Provides
        SqlDatabase database(SqlDatabaseImpl sqlDatabase) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestLogInjectedClassName.Module.class.getName())
                    .info("Providing " + sqlDatabase.getClass());
            return sqlDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            //TODO: other bindings
        }
    }

    class AlternativeModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Provides
        SqlDatabase database(AlternativeImpl sqlDatabase) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestLogInjectedClassName.Module.class.getName())
                    .info("Providing " + sqlDatabase.getClass());
            return sqlDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            //TODO: other bindings
        }
    }

    /**
     * Just log
     */
    class LoggingInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).info(methodInvocation.getStaticPart().toString());
            return methodInvocation.proceed();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Binds an interceptor on any method of any class implementing SqlDatabase
     */
    class AopModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindInterceptor(Matchers.subclassesOf(SqlDatabase.class), Matchers.any(), new LoggingInterceptor());

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
        injector.getInstance(SqlDatabase.class);

        Injector anotheInjector = Guice.createInjector(new AlternativeModule());
        anotheInjector.getInstance(SqlDatabase.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void testAop() {
        Injector aopInjector = Guice.createInjector(new AopModule(), new Module());
        aopInjector.getInstance(SqlDatabase.class).doSomething();

        Injector alterntiveAopInjector = Guice.createInjector(new AopModule(), new AlternativeModule());
        alterntiveAopInjector.getInstance(SqlDatabase.class).doSomething();
    }

}
```

When I run `test()` heres my console

```
Dec 10, 2017 9:12:15 AM stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$Module database
INFO: Providing class stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$SqlDatabaseImpl
Dec 10, 2017 9:12:15 AM stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$AlternativeModule database
INFO: Providing class stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$AlternativeImpl
```

When I run `testAop()` here's my console. Please note that in this case we log both the injection *and* the execution of the method. You may choose to log only the execution by removing the log in the `@Provides` method. Also note that is only possible when Guice creates your instance of `SqlDatabase` and methods in its implementations are *not* final. (I did not format the log code below as lines were being chopped in the preview)

Dec 10, 2017 9:14:01 AM stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$Module database
INFO: Providing class stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$SqlDatabaseImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$d7a0782d
Dec 10, 2017 9:14:01 AM stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$LoggingInterceptor invoke
INFO: public void stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$SqlDatabaseImpl.doSomething()
foo
Dec 10, 2017 9:14:01 AM stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$AlternativeModule database
INFO: Providing class stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$AlternativeImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$3ef8fbf1
Dec 10, 2017 9:14:01 AM stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$LoggingInterceptor invoke
INFO: public void stackoverflowscrapbook.TestLogInjectedClassName$AlternativeImpl.doSomething()
bar

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, neither of these methods have any way to get to the context before the injection is complete, or to change/initialize the object in different ways depending on where it's being injected.